# Javascript function in php loop

Tags: javascript, php, function, while-loop

I have a PHP while loop (extracting data from database) and I need to call a Javascript function during each step of the loop.

The Javascript function have to use some parameters of the loop and print a result.

Example:

```
<script>
function example(param1,param2){
  ....
  return result;
}
</script>

<?php
while(...){
..
?>
<input type="hidden" id="param1" value="<?=$param1>?" />
<input type="hidden" id="param2" value="<?=$param2>?" />
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
   var param1=$("#param1").val();
   var param2=$("#param2").val();
   var result=example(param1,param2);
   $("#result").html(result);
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what the javascript function will do ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do inside the loop by JavaScript? I guess you can handle that by php itself

Comment: IDs need to be unique within an HTML document - go fix that first of all.

Comment: @CBroe where are IDs not unique in my code?

Comment: Seriously? You are outputting `<input type="hidden" id="param1"` inside a loop. Now make a guess how many elements with the id `param1` this will result in, depending on how many times your loop runs …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use incremented `$i` in your loop. 
I have updated your code as below-

```
<script>
function example(param1,param2){
  ....
  return result;
}
</script>

<?php
$i=1;
while(...){
..
?>
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $i; ?>-param1" value="<?=$param1>?" />
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $i; ?>-param2" value="<?=$param2>?" />
<div id="<?php echo $i?>-result"></div>
<script>
   var param1=$("#<?php echo $i; ?>param1").val();
   var param2=$("#<?php echo $i; ?>param2").val();
   var result=example(param1,param2);
   $("#<?php echo $i; ?>-result").html(result);
</script>
<?php
$i=$i+1;
}
?>
```